# How to set Cancel url in facebook app used for oauth 2 signup/login?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

i am setting up facebook login on my website.

if user likes to join my site using facebook credentials , then when user clicks on **sign up/In using facebook** he is redirected to the facebook page where he is shown **dialog** whether he wants to approve permissions or cancel.

like this

[image: facebook login oauth permission page]

if he clicks **Okay** he then redirected to the my site with details forwarded by facebook.,

but if he clicks **Cancel** then he is not redirected to my web site , he stays on the same page while page reloads and he is offered the dialog box again.

this doesnt feel right, after user clicks cancel he should be redirected to someplace, so how can i set where to redirect the user after he clicks Cancel , on the grant permissions page ?

update: other questions on so doesnt have proper answer, so lloking for more acurate answwr.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the Login Button or FB.login()?

If you are using FB.login, you can track the response and whatever choice people make, the browser returns to the app and the response data indicating whether they connected or cancelled is sent to your app. You can handle it exactly the way you want it to behave.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
   // Logged into your app and Facebook.
 } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
   // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
 } else {
   // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
   // they are logged into this app or not.
 }
});
```